# Unable to install ydata-profiling on macOS

Tags: python, macos, pip

I could not install ydata-profiling on my macOS (13.3.1 (a))

```
(Studysession) chao@chaos-MacBook-Pro Desktop % pip install ydata-profiling 
Collecting ydata-profiling
  Using cached ydata_profiling-4.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (352 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy<1.11,>=1.4.1 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from ydata-profiling) (1.10.1)
Collecting pandas!=1.4.0,<2,>1.1 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached pandas-1.5.3-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (10.8 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib<4,>=3.2 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from ydata-profiling) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pydantic<2,>=1.8.1 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from ydata-profiling) (1.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML<6.1,>=5.0.0 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from ydata-profiling) (6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2<3.2,>=2.11.1 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from ydata-profiling) (3.1.2)
Collecting visions[type_image_path]==0.7.5 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached visions-0.7.5-py3-none-any.whl (102 kB)
Collecting numpy<1.24,>=1.16.0 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached numpy-1.23.5-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (13.3 MB)
Collecting htmlmin==0.1.12 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached htmlmin-0.1.12-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting phik<0.13,>=0.11.1 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached phik-0.12.3-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (649 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.24.0 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from ydata-profiling) (2.31.0)
Collecting tqdm<5,>=4.48.2 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached tqdm-4.65.0-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting seaborn<0.13,>=0.10.1 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached seaborn-0.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (293 kB)
Collecting multimethod<2,>=1.4 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached multimethod-1.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting statsmodels<1,>=0.13.2 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached statsmodels-0.14.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (9.4 MB)
Collecting typeguard<3,>=2.13.2 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached typeguard-2.13.3-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting imagehash==4.3.1 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached ImageHash-4.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (296 kB)
Collecting wordcloud>=1.9.1 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached wordcloud-1.9.2.tar.gz (222 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting dacite>=1.8 (from ydata-profiling)
  Using cached dacite-1.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting PyWavelets (from imagehash==4.3.1->ydata-profiling)
  Using cached PyWavelets-1.4.1-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (4.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from imagehash==4.3.1->ydata-profiling) (9.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.3.0 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from visions[type_image_path]==0.7.5->ydata-profiling) (23.1.0)
Collecting networkx>=2.4 (from visions[type_image_path]==0.7.5->ydata-profiling)
  Using cached networkx-3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting tangled-up-in-unicode>=0.0.4 (from visions[type_image_path]==0.7.5->ydata-profiling)
  Using cached tangled_up_in_unicode-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from jinja2<3.2,>=2.11.1->ydata-profiling) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.2->ydata-profiling) (1.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.2->ydata-profiling) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.2->ydata-profiling) (4.39.4)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.2->ydata-profiling) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.2->ydata-profiling) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.2->ydata-profiling) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from matplotlib<4,>=3.2->ydata-profiling) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas!=1.4.0,<2,>1.1->ydata-profiling) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.14.1 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from phik<0.13,>=0.11.1->ydata-profiling) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.2.0 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pydantic<2,>=1.8.1->ydata-profiling) (4.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.24.0->ydata-profiling) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.24.0->ydata-profiling) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.24.0->ydata-profiling) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.24.0->ydata-profiling) (2023.5.7)
Collecting patsy>=0.5.2 (from statsmodels<1,>=0.13.2->ydata-profiling)
  Using cached patsy-0.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (233 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./Studysession/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from patsy>=0.5.2->statsmodels<1,>=0.13.2->ydata-profiling) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: wordcloud
  Building wheel for wordcloud (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/wordcloud_cli.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/tokenization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/wordcloud.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/color_from_image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/stopwords -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud
      copying wordcloud/DroidSansMono.ttf -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud
      UPDATING build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud/_version.py
      set build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud/_version.py to '1.9.2'
      running build_ext
      building 'wordcloud.query_integral_image' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/chaoxu/Desktop/Studysession/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c wordcloud/query_integral_image.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/wordcloud/query_integral_image.o
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for wordcloud
  Running setup.py clean for wordcloud
Failed to build wordcloud
ERROR: Could not build wheels for wordcloud, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The first error thrown was this:
[image]

The subprogress is like this:
[image]
I have tried to `pip install pyproject.toml`, it was succesful. But it does change the result that I still could not install `ydata-profiling` on my laptop.

Can anyone give me a hint? I want to use the ProfileReport function to summarize a dataset.

Comment: Seems the error is "**xcrun: error: invalid active developer path**"

Comment: Thank you, Gino. I am downloading the Xcode. Your answer is very helpful!

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)